# Custom font family with siunitx

Tags: fontspec, siunitx

I'm trying to set some relatively large tables in my document. I used fontspec to create a new font family, which I use only to set tables. Specifically, I'm using the Bell Centennial font to set my tables.

I've defined the font family with:

```
\newfontfamily\bellcentennial[
    Path = fonts/BC/ ,
    Extension = .otf ,
    UprightFont = *-Address ,
    BoldFont = *-NameNum
]{BellCentennialStd}
```

My problem is, I have no idea how to setup siunitx to use the `\bellcentennial` font family. Using `detect-family` just gives me the standard math roman font.

This should be an acceptable MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newfontfamily\bellcentennial[
    Path = fonts/BC/ ,
    Extension = .otf ,
    UprightFont = *-Address ,
    BoldFont = *-NameNum
]{BellCentennialStd}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\begingroup
    \bellcentennial
    \fontsize{6pt}{6pt}
    \selectfont
    \begin{tabular}{r S S}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Label}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Numbers}} \\
        Foo & 1.2 & 3.4 \\
        Bar & 5.6 & 7.8 \\
        Baz & 9.0 & 12.34 \\
        Qux & 56.789 & 0.0 \\
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup
    \caption{The most wonderous of tables.}
    \label{tab:tableytabletable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
\end{table}
```

Of course, unless you have the Bell Centennial fonts and use the same folder structure as I do, you are going to have to redefine the definition of the `\bellcentennial` font family to work locally.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious with setting up siunitx but I'm unsure of where to start looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine what `text-rm` does.

I changed the font with a very distinctive one, not having yours.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newfontfamily\bellcentennial[
%    Path = fonts/BC/ ,
%    Extension = .otf ,
%    UprightFont = *-Address ,
%    BoldFont = *-NameNum
%]{BellCentennialStd}
  Ligatures=TeX
]{Futura}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{detect-all,text-rm=\bellcentennial}
\centering
\begingroup\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\bellcentennial

\begin{tabular}{r S S}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Label}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Numbers}} \\
  Foo & 1.2 & 3.4 \\
  Bar & 5.6 & 7.8 \\
  Baz & 9.0 & 12.34 \\
  Qux & 56.789 & 0.0 \\
\end{tabular}

\endgroup

\caption{The most wonderous of tables.}\label{tab:tableytabletable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]